# How do I change a Feature Delegation, in IIS, only for specific websites?

Tags: iis

I have a website that requires access-sslFlags to be set for certain endpoints.

This requires that the SSL Settings Feature Delegation be changed from "Read Only" to "Read/Write" on the server.

Is there a way to change this setting only for a specific website, rather than for the server as a whole?

I've been doing this through IIS Manager, and I can see nothing that might do this.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS Manager, select the server.

In the Security Group, you'll see an icon for "Feature Delegation". Double-click that.

On the Feature Delegation page, you'll see a list of the various configurable features.

In the right panel, under "Actions" you'll see two more options, "Reset All Delegation", and "Custom Site Delegation".

(If you've selected a feature, you'll also see options for "Read/Write", "Read Only", "Not Delegated", and "Reset to Inherited". Ignore them for now.)

Click on "Custom Site Delegation".

You'll see the "Custom Site Delegation" page, which shows the same list of features you saw before, but above it you'll see a dropdown of the websites installed on the server.

Select the website you want to change from the dropdown.

Click on the feature you want to unlock.

In the right panel, click on "Read/Write".